# PrestaShop 1.7.x multiple prices

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm currently writing a module for prestashop to have 3 basic prices for customers(retail, small wholesale, big wholesale), each applied depending on total cart price
*(if totalPrice>1000 apply small wholesale, if totalPrice>2000 apply big wholesale)*
I have some idea how to implement but i want to know
a)how is price being calculated and stored in presta
b)how to add additional fields into pricing of product to enter different prices
Also, i read that it should be implemented using hooks, but i dont understand how exactly they work

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i tried overriding Product.php and AdminProductsController.php as it seemed logical but still dont understand how to do it right

Comment: You can't apply a product price depending on cart price, it's recursive!!